# Laravel admin update users' info, duplicate email entry when updating his own admin account information

Tags: php, laravel, validation, duplicates

I am working on a laravel 8 application and using *spatie/laravel-permission* for roles and permissions. On the admin page, I'm displaying all users which the admin can do CRUD operations on. The users list also includes his own admin account.

The problem I'm having is when updating user details. The admin can successfully update user account information for other users with validation. However, if the admin tries to edit the information of his own admin account, the validation passes but I get an SQL error :

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'admin@email.com'
> for key 'users_email_unique'

See below my `UserController` `update` method for updating user information with validation:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $edit_user_rules = array(
        // ... other validation rules ...
        
        //'email' => "required|email|unique:users,email,{{$user->id}}", //. auth()->user()->id,
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
        
        // ... other validation rules ...
    );
    
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $edit_user_rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        Session::flash('failed', 'Failed to save User details!');
        return redirect(route('editUser', ['user' => $user->id]))->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    } else {
        $validated = $validator->validated();
        $updatedUser = User::find($user)->first();

        // ... other user fields ...
        $updatedUser->username = $validated['username'];
        $updatedUser->email = $validated['email'];
        // ... other user fields ...
        
        if ($updatedUser->save()) {
            return redirect(route('allUsers'));
        } else {
            return redirect(route('allUsers')); // with errors
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use different validation rules on the `email` field, for example,

`"required|email|unique:users,email,{{$user->id}}"`
`"required|email|unique:users,email," . auth()->user()->id`

but none worked. So I used a validation `Rule` to validate the unique email field. It works fine when I try to update other users' information but I get the SQL duplicate email error when updating the admin's own account.

Would appreciate any help I can get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is getting passed the validation rules, but it's failing when it saves the rule. This is because you're not getting the user properly. `find()` automatically gets the first record, so `first()` is unneeded, and is actually probably pulling the wrong account. When I try `User::find(3)->first()` locally, I'm getting user 1 instead of user 3. Remove `first()` from your call.

```
$updatedUser = User::find($user->id);
```

Comment: i had to change it to `User::find($user->id)` and it worked fine thanks! `find($user)` was actually returning a Collection of more than 1 User. Using `first()` was indeed returning the wrong user - bit out of scope, but why does that happen? I thought it just returns the first object from the collection

Comment: It usually does, but as you mentioned, `User::find($user)` returned a collection instead of a single user, so `first()` returned the first of that collection.

Comment: Though actually this line is completely unnecessary. You already have the user from `public function update(Request $request, User $user)`, so you just need to modify that `$user` without re-fetching it.

Comment: makes sense, but then this raises the question as to why I was getting a collection using `find($user)` but was getting 1 correct user record with `find($user->id)`. Doesn't laravel's type hinted parameter search by ID by default?

Comment: Apparently not. I just logged the sql request on the find with the object, and it passed in each property value, changing it to an `IN` request. So `User::find($user)` looks like `select * from \`users\` where \`users\`.\`id\` in (3, 'myemail@email', 'My name', 1, ...)`  Considering I have a few boolean flags in my users table, it pulled 2 users: 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't determined which column should be unique to ignore him self.

Change your email validation line to :

```
'email' => ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($user->id)],
```

Don't forget to put this like to top of your code `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;` .

Comment: I hope I was able to help.

Comment: tried changing it but still got the same error